# How to get a readable string from BSON object

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

I have a `org.bson.conversions.Bson` object that I'd like to turn into something readable for debugging.

I've tried using the Mongo JSON util for this, but i get `RuntimeException`s, saying it can't serialize the type `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$AndFilter`

```
Bson query = ...
String json = com.mongodb.util.JSON.serialize(query);
```

Which does tell me something about the structure of the BSON, but I'd still like to have it readable somehow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert a `Bson` instance to a `BsonDocument` using [toBsonDocument](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/org/bson/conversions/Bson.html#toBsonDocument-java.lang.Class-org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry-) and then use `BsonDocument.toJson()`.

For example ...

```
Bson bson = Filters.eq("name", "Bob");

BsonDocument asBsonDocument = bson.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, 
    MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());

System.out.println(asBsonDocument.toJson());
```

... will print:

```
{ "name" : "Bob" }
```

Comment: In more recent driver versions, `MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry()` needs to be used instead of `MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry()`.